# Bootstrap accordion - Collapse with css are not expanding the way I wanted

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am Trying to get this Collapsibles working to no avail, I am not sure what I am doing wrong if
any ? I suspect my PHP, but it works fine I guess when it is loading the right text from
Database ? any help will be appreciated.
See attached screenshots: when I click to expand Post#1, all other posts will expand as well, I wanted to hide all posts when one is active.. this is not working for me here .

[This is my JSfiddle here][2]

[image: Expanded posts/collapsed posts]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/324ycoh9/4/

Answer (score 1):

Assign a unique ID to each block (Note the $key)

```
<?php
     $posts = array(
      array(
        'title' => 'title1', 
        'text' => 'text1'
        ),
      array(
        'title' => 'title2', 
        'text' => 'text2'
        ),
      array(
        'title' => 'title3', 
        'text' => 'text3'
        )
      );
    ?>
    
    <html>

    <head>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="accordion" class="myaccordion">
    <?php
        foreach($posts as $key=>$element){
    ?>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading<?=$key?>">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?=$key?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<?=$key?>">
              <?php print $element['title']; ?>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<?=$key?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?=$key?>" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            <?php print $element['text']; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, getting posts is already happening, the issue I have is that when I click on (-) or (+) to collapse, all other elements are collapsing.
Thank you.

Comment: Anyone looking at this to guide me to a different approach please ?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are curious to see how I solved this, here is what I finally got:

```
<body>
                <div id="accordion" class="myaccordion">
                <?php if(!empty($eventInfo) && count($eventInfo)>0)
                { 
                foreach($eventInfo as $key=>$element) 
                {
                ?>  
                    <div class="card">      
                        <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php print $element['id'];?>">         
                            <h2 class="mb-0">               
                                <button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php print $element['id'];?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<?php print $element['id'];?>">
                                <?php print $element['title']; ?>
                                    <span  class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fas fa-minus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse<?php print $element['id'];?>" class="collapse collapsed" aria-labelledby="heading<?php print $element['id'];?>" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <?php print $element['content']; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                }
                }
                ?> 
                </div>                  
            </body>
```